Why can I connect simplex at 146.52 but not at 145.200 and 147.000?
I am preparing myself to use Winlink.
I am preparing myself to use VARA FM.
145.000 is the Simplex frequency used by our local university (Montana State). It can be used for both voice and digital, the Simplex Controller stated on April 9, 2024. However, when not using Winlink (or VARA FM), and when not attempting to use off the schedule of the Simplex MSU schedule, a pair of hams can not use that frequency locally for a Simplex communication. (We are not using the university antennas, of course, but rather, our personal rubber ducks.)

You really haven't provided enough information for someone to venture a guess as to what could be wrong.  Are try trying to connect with winlink? How certain are you that there is something listening at those two frequencies? Why are you sure? What have you tried?

I am not using Winlink (yet). P2P Simplex. HTs.

We still need a lot more information.  How far apart are you?  Tell us about the antennas and intervening terrain...  Are you just trying to key up and not breaking squelch?

I tried to give you time to fix this but you have added no details.  If you decide to edit the question with additional details that respond to the comments I'll be glad to reopen the question.

While winlink does have some commonly used frequencies, the ones you have listed are not in that list.  In partcular, 146.52 is the 2m FM voice calling frequency and should not be used for digital modes like winlink.
Additionally, just because there is a standard list of frequencies doesn't mean you can just pick one and expect to get a connection.  You need to find out if there are winlink gateways in your local area (since you are using VHF and not HF) and find out which specific frequency the closest one uses.

We have no Winlink Repeaters in our area. Since the local college uses a particular frequency for simplex (voice), your information may reveal why we can not use that frequency. Thank you for your insights!
